# Users that give shiurim

Tags: discussion

Wow do some of you guys know torah!
I'd like to learn more from y'all. Do any of the more active users on Mi Yodeya give shuirim somewhere online that I can listen to?

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/50842853#50842853

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/49852718#49852718

Comment: https://crownheights.info/chabad-news/465607/crown-heightser-comes-in-second-at-tanach-chidon/#comment-304576  and https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9246380#9246380 (That's the other Alex.)

Comment: @Alex, is it really the other Alex? Lol

Comment: Well I guess technically *I'm* the other Alex.

Comment: Haha, good Shuir I just heard it!

Comment: I try to write a weekly devar Torah, if that counts. You can see it at https://parashaponders.com

Comment: @Alex I see you're the bucki in tanach. Perhaps you can help me out with a tactic to remember chunks of psukim of tanach at once? Thanks !

Comment: @FalseMessiah That's [the other Alex](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/37/alex).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**User: ShteiShulchanos**

He joined the site not too long ago, I told him about it. He gives shuir on: Daf Yomi, Mesilas Yesharim, Kitzur Shulchan Aruch, Noam Elimelech on the Parsha, a couple of other modern day seforim, and he'd like to start giving shuir on some other seforim as well. Young guy, lives in America. I'm actually a good friend of his.